# CoreText causes enormous memory consumption?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-text

My application usually only takes up ~40M of memory but when Core Text is used VSIZE jumps up to ~300M. How can I get Core Text to use less memory?

**P.S.** : I use lots of Core Text objects.

**P.S. 2** : I use 'top' to get memory info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, VSIZE is not really a good indicator of how much "memory" your app is using.  It is more an indicator of how much of your virtual address space is in use, which includes things like memory (RAM), mmap-ed files, etc.  For 64-bit apps in particular, VSIZE will *always* be large (> 1 GB).

If you want to know how much physical memory you're using, check RSIZE instead.

Have you noticed anything abnormal about your program?  Does the memory usage grow over time when using CoreText?  If so then you may have a leak, in which case the best approach would be to profile your app using Instruments to see if your code is leaking.

Comment: For garbage-collected apps, VSIZE will be *very* large—so large that we had to add a section to our user documentation about it: http://growl.info/documentation/faq.php#growlmenu-vsize

Comment: @Peter Hosey Very interesting, Peter. Thanks for the link.

Comment: No, the memory usage becomes high as soon as core text is used.

Answer (score 1):

One note about CoreText I've found is that if you create a font without an exact font name, CoreText will load *every* font into mapped memory as part of its search to find your font (and it doesn't seem to ever release that memory).  Use Instruments with Virtual Memory tracking and look in the "mapped_file" section to see if all of the fonts are loaded there.  In any case CoreText does use a fairly large amount of memory.